# Error - INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert the number_of orders into storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try.The calculations are done in another table (storiacloud.vw_storia_oms_orders). The promblem is that it is trying to insert school_ucn as well but i am just using that for group by and do not want to insert that. Can somebody please help

```
INSERT INTO storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try
(no_of_orders)
select school_ucn,count(otc_order_number)
from storiacloud.vw_storia_oms_orders
group by school_ucn;
```

Comment: Just remove the unwanted column from the SELECT. But what use will the counts be without context of which school they relate to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove it from the select:

```
INSERT INTO storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try (no_of_orders) 
select count(otc_order_number) 
from storiacloud.vw_storia_oms_orders
group by school_ucn;
```

It will still group, just not report it. I'm not sure what use a bunch of random numbers in a table is though.

Comment: Nothing is coming on to No_of_orders coumn   storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try  .. the new query is INSERT INTO storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try
(no_of_orders)
select count(otc_order_number)
from storiacloud.vw_storia_oms_orders as a
inner join 
storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try as b
on a.school_ucn = b.ucn
group by school_ucn;

Comment: Thanks i have added the relation between the schools

Comment: But the message says INSERT INTO storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try successful
1829 rows affected

Execution time: 1.25s

Answer (score 0):

... or add the missing column in the INSERT's list of columns:

```
INSERT INTO storiacloud.schl_storia_school_status_try
   (no_of_orders,   [YOUR_NB_ORDER_COLUMN]    )
select school_ucn,count(otc_order_number)
from storiacloud.vw_storia_oms_orders
group by school_ucn;
```